# What is a good expression for saying that two things share some similaraties?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I believe there was an expression for it, it was something like 'x and z come into or meet at a similarity when it comes to.......'

Comment: There are numerous ways to answer this question. You could say **x and z are similar when it comes to..** or **x and z are the same when comparing...**.  **One can draw similarities between x and z when comparing....** **x and z converge at a similarity when comparing their...**. This question is pretty opinionated, but those are a few examples.

Comment: so it is valid to say: 'x and z coverage at similarities when it comes to a, b, and z.'? or should it be a similarity?

Comment: Definition of converge is tend to meet at a point. If you are saying they converge at similarities, you are saying the meet similarity at that point. **The two cars features converge at a similarity when it comes to horsepower.** is an example of using this.

Comment: so if I want to mention three similarities I would say: 'they converge at a similarity when it comes to horsepower, engine, and price.'

Comment: Yes but I realized one mistake I made(apologize, I'm in an English lecture at the moment so a bit occupied). The two cars converge **on** similarity when it comes to horsepower, engine, and price. What you're saying is is that the two vehicles have a similarity when it comes to horsepower, engine, and price. I should note that's a fairly formal way of saying it, and less conversational.

Comment: I dunno about converge at a similarity.....I would not use that myself. That said: two opinions might converge on a subject.....but objects generally do not unless describing lines that converge. The roads converge at [some point]....

Comment: The vernacular is, "Item A and item B have something in common."  You've been to Oslo. I've been to Oslo.  We have something in common.

Answer (score 1):

**A, B and C are similar** in that they share some of the same features.
**A, B and C share the same mathematical features**.

**There is similarity between A, B and C because** [argument].

**The arguments used by A, B and C converge** when describing [some thing].

Answer (score 1):

A and B have something in common.